# Using class , function and method variables

Tags: python, function, class, methods

**Case1:**

```
def ABS(ogh):                     
    print "XYZ is good"    

ABS('jk')
```

Works fine.

**Case2:**

```
class A(object):                           
      def ABS(ogh):                     
          print "XYZ is good"    

a=A()                                      
a.ABS('jk')
```

> TypeError: ABS() takes exactly 1 argument 2 given)

**Case3:-**

```
class A(object):                           
      def ABS(ogh):                     
          print "XYZ is good"    

a=A()                                      
a.ABS()
```

This one works fine.

My doubt is why do I get error in *Case2* and why there is no requirement of a variable while calling the function/method(here, since under class) ABS defined inside the class A?

Comment: Methods need a `self` argument.

Comment: I think you need a refresh on how to define classes and use methods in Python.

Comment: All class methods have the "self" parameter passed invisibly. You need to add it to the list of params or you'll get this "too many args" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define methods inside of a class, python implicitly passes a reference to the class as the first parameter. By custom this is called self. So in your Case 2 example, you get a TypeError saying you've given two arguments because python has passed a reference to your class A object which you've bound to the variable ogh, and then your explicitly passed argument 'jk' is unexpected.

Using this knowledge we can update your case to to the following which produces the expected result.

```
class A(object):                           
      def ABS(self, ogh):                     
          print "XYZ is good"    

a=A()                                      
a.ABS('jk')
```

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful ;)